# Remove deformation in distorted image?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

I'm fairly new to Computer Vision and OpenCV. I'm working on a project in which we are building a robot that plays snooker. We installed a camera on top of the table, with the aim of detecting the balls. I originally assumed that getting rid of the barrel distortion would be quite straight forward. However, I'm not very satisfied with the results I'm getting. In the second image I attached, one can clearly see, that after applying the undistortion transformation, the sides of the table are not parallel to each other. Moreover, with respect to the first image, the balls are deformed into a sort of egg shape.

Does anyone have an idea of how I could fix this issues? I tried to take more picture of the chessboard patter is as many different positions as possible, without any visible changes. Also using more parameters to model the distortion didn't seem to yield any improvements.

[Distorted Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7slIO.jpg)
[Undistorted Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cRFA.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's difficult to say what's wrong without any math/code. Could you please include that as well?

Comment: Maybe it was kinda naive, but I just followed the following [tutorial](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_calib3d/py_calibration/py_calibration.html). I only adapted the grid size to match mine.

Comment: I see. How did the output of the calibration look? Were the reprojection errors low enough? In my experience, Opencv's calibration is not the best, I strongly recomment using https://github.com/ethz-asl/kalibr. Also, again from experience, aprilgrids work better than chessboards in general.

Comment: I get a reprojection error of 0.079. I'll definitely try to use the tool from ASL and see if things improve. Thank you very much for the suggestion.

Comment: I tried to use the Kalibr code, but I seem to have some issues. I run their sample and it just worked fine. But whenever I try to my own rosbag it seems to fail. I'm still trying to use a checkboard pattern, it tells me the whole time that no patter can be detected, while I'm sure that I set everything correctly in the yaml file. Did you ever have any such issues?

Comment: Yes but it has been a while... Usually it's a bit painful to know what is wrong, I know... Have you tried running it with the verbose flag? It lets you see the feature point detections and you more or less can get a feeling for what is wrong.